# Making shortcuts on the launcher with .desktop

Tags: shortcut-keys, .desktop

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, and I want to make a keyboard shortcut for some software, but I don't understand what should be filled in for the "Name" and "Command".

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you trying to make a `.desktop` file to put on your launcher?  I have removed the part about the keyboard from the title as your question doesn't mention that.  Feel free to add it back, but please clarify.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may choose whatever you want for `Name`.

For `Command` you are to find what the executable of your software is. To do so: start a software, then run a terminal end execute `ps axww` there. In the tail of output you are to find the exact name of your executable (it will look like `/usr/bin/MyGreateSw` or `/opt/MyGreateSw/bin/mygreatesw`.) 
The latter is the string to put as *command*.

Answer (score 0):

Name is the name that is displayed when you hover over the file on the launcher. Command is the command that you would run in a terminal to run the software.